# What bring(s) you here or Who know(s)?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Why do we add "**s**" in verb like *bring* and *know* even though we don't whether a subject is singular or plural?

Answer (score 1):

It's just the usual way, that we regard the unknown subject as singular.

- Who knows?  The answer can be plural **They know** or singular **He knows**

You can make it plural by rephrasing:

- How many **know**?  The answer can again be plural **They all know** or singular **Only he knows**.